# How can I show a flat representation of a GtkTreeStore in a GtkTreeView?

Tags: sorting, haskell, gtk, gtktreeview, treemodel

I have a TreeStore with objects that I view and manipulate through a `GtkTreeView`/`GtkTreeModel` setup.

I also have a TreeView showing a TreeModelSort of the TreeStore, which I use for sorting on columns like name and date.

The problem is, that the sort mechanism only sorts the root nodes, even if a underlying child node has e.g. a date that is later/sooner than the roo tnodes' dates.

So, the question is if there is any way to show the objects as a `List`, not a tree, but keeping the references to the paths in the other TreeView?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a TreeModelFilter that filters out any rows that are child rows (ie, depth > 1). You can filter your sorted model, and display just the root nodes.